# Show first div by default

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
 .newboxes {
        display: none;

    }

  <script language="javascript">
    function showonlyone(thechosenone) {
         $('.newboxes').each(function(index) {
              if ($(this).attr("id") == thechosenone) {
                   $(this).show(200);
              }
              else {
                   $(this).hide(600);
              }
         });
    }
  </script>

<a href="javascript:showonlyone('newboxes1');" id="myHeader1">
<a href="javascript:showonlyone('newboxes2');" id="myHeader2">
<a href="javascript:showonlyone('newboxes3');" id="myHeader3">
<a href="javascript:showonlyone('newboxes4');" id="myHeader4">

<div class="newboxes" id="newboxes1" style="display: none;padding: 0px; width: 750px; font-size:14px;">
<div class="newboxes" id="newboxes2" style="display: none;padding: 0px; width: 750px; font-size:14px;">
<div class="newboxes" id="newboxes3" style="display: none;padding: 0px; width: 750px; font-size:14px;">
<div class="newboxes" id="newboxes4" style="display: none;padding: 0px; width: 750px; font-size:14px;">
```

I want to show first  when page load first time. How should I do it with this piece of code? If I add display: block; to first div it dosn't work like that.

Comment: Maybe you aught to start by closing your tags.

Comment: The anchor and the div tags are not closed. your dom structure is not valid

Comment: remove `display:none` form the first div. and change the CSS too. Infact if you are gonna use inline styles, don't worry about that CSS at all

Answer (score 0):

Change the first one to display:block

```
<div class="newboxes" id="newboxes1" style="display: block;padding: 0px; width: 750px; font-size:14px;">
```

OR select using id:

```
#newboxes1{
    display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this CSS in your code:

```
.newboxes:first-child {
    display: block;
}
```

And remove the inline display property from all the divs.

```
<div class="newboxes" id="newboxes1" style="padding: 0px; width: 750px; font-size:14px;">
```

Comment: Why would you use `:first-child` when the element has a unique `ID`?

Comment: @Connor so that they can use it any where means on other page where can be different ID.

Answer (score 0):

```
  function showonlyone(thechosenone) {
         $('.newboxes').each(function(index) {
              if ($(this).attr("id") == thechosenone) {
                   $(this).show(200);
              }
              else {
                   $(this).hide(600);
              }
         });
    } 

// This will show first box :eq(n) returns the nth item from the selector (starting from 0)
$('.newboxes:eq(0)').show();
```